# can I use spring profile for data.sql to load different data based on environment?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

[image]

let's say I have 2 sets of data,

1 set for production, another for development
currently I just manually comment and uncomment in the data.sql

How to separate dev and prod environment for data.sql ?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override the location and/or the name of the files Spring Boot will use to create your schema and load your data in application*.properties (or yml).
So you can have :

application-dev.properties with :

```
# "Old" Spring boot version
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:schema-dev.sql
spring.datasource.data=classpath:data-dev.sql

# New Spring boot version
spring.sql.init.schema-locations=classpath:schema-dev.sql
spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:data-dev.sql
```

application-prod.properties with :

```
# "Old" Spring boot version
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:schema-prod.sql
spring.datasource.data=classpath:data-prod.sql

# New Spring boot version
spring.sql.init.schema-locations=classpath:schema-prod.sql
spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:data-prod.sql
```

And then you can use Spring Profil as usual to use one or the other configuration.

Notes :

- The "Old" Spring boot version is probably recent. I figured that the `spring.datasource.*` properties are deprecated when creating a new app today, and can't find the exact version.
- Also, you don't have to use the properties to define your schema if you don't need it, I just put it there to complete the answer.