# Spring Boot test with @Sql & H2 gives JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation

Tags: hibernate, testing, h2, unique-constraint, spring-boot-test

I have a simple Spring Boot (2.6.1) test, which throws:

```
 JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
 Unique index or primary key violation
```

The test loads data from `test/resources/data.sql`, which has a single statement:

```
INSERT INTO country (name) VALUES ('Italy');
```

The Test class is:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
    public class FailingTest {

   @Test
   @Sql("/data.sql")
   void test(){
       assertTrue(true);
   }
}
```

The domain class is:

```
@Entity 
public class Country {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
   private Integer id;

   @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
   private String name;
}
```

The `application.properties` file contains:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

The exception message is:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException:
Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [data.sql]: 
INSERT INTO country (name) VALUES ('Italy'); 
nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
Unique index or primary key violation: 
"PUBLIC.UK_LLIDYP77H6XKEOKPBMOY710D4_INDEX_6 ON PUBLIC.COUNTRY(NAME) 
VALUES ( /* key:1 */ 2, 'Italy')"; 
SQL statement:INSERT INTO country (name) VALUES ('Italy') [23505-200]
```

There **no** other sql scripts in the app, sql data is **not** loded programatically either and Country is **not** referenced by other entities. The test is run as a single test.

It seems the INSERT statement is executed twice, which violates the unique condition for the column. But why?!

When I replace `@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)` with `@Column(nullable = false)` everything works fine!

Any ideas what is happening? Workarounds?

Comment: Hi @enhancedJack How did you resolve this. I want to write integration tests and have data.sql in src/main/resources and also in src/test/resources. I want tests to use one in src/test/resources and should not execute src/main/resources.

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is about Spring Boot auto-configuration feature. The framework treats file named `data.sql` as default initializer. What actually happens here:

1. When application context is fully configured, Spring Boot executes `data.sql` as initial SQL source.
2. When JUnit invokes `test()` method, it tries to execute `data.sql` again due to `@Sql` annotation presence.
3. Unique constraint is violated. Exception is thrown.

There are multiple ways to deal with the problem:

1. Change the file's name (e.g., `init-data.sql`). In this case, Spring won't execute it on application context start.
2. Change Spring Boot `spring.datasource.initialization-mode` property to `never`.
3. Move script to any subfolder.

Comment: Hi @Semyon Kirekov I am facing same issue. I want to write integration tests and have data.sql in src/main/resources and also in src/test/resources. I want tests to use one in src/test/resources and should not execute src/main/resources.

Comment: @SammyPawar
You can override the specified `data.sql` in `application.properties`. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68825858/can-i-use-spring-profile-for-data-sql-to-load-different-data-based-on-environmen).

Comment: doing it this way 

@ SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ ActiveProfiles("test")
@ TestPropertySource(properties = { "spring.config.location=classpath:application-test.yml" })
public class IntegrationTest {

    @ LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    private String baseUrl = "http://localhost";

@ Sql({"/schema-test.sql", "/data-test.sql"})

Comment: My work around this issue was to disable the data source SQL with the property: `initialization-mode: never` and have an explicit SQL annotation on the tests `@Sql("/data.sql")`