# How to load data.sql in spring-data-jpa conditional by active profile?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

`spring-boot` automatically loads `schema.sql` and `data.sql` on startup.

Question: is it possible to add a profile condition to this?

Like: `schema-production.sql`, so that Spring loads `schema-${spring.profiles.active}.sql` only?

This would be similar to the already working approach of `application-{profile}.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

I solution might be linked in: [can I use spring profile for data.sql to load different data based on environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68825858/can-i-use-spring-profile-for-data-sql-to-load-different-data-based-on-environmen)

The clue is to override the file locations inside the `application-${profile}.properties`:

`application-dev.properties`:

```
spring.sql.init.schema-locations=classpath:schema-dev.sql
spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:data-dev.sql
```